# Address family not supported gRPC Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, python-3.6, grpc-python

While trying to run Python gRPC server from Docker with host as localhost, getting an error "**Address family not supported**"

This is for a gRPC server written in Python 3.6 inside Docker on Ubuntu 18.04 Host. Tried replacing "**localhost**" with **0.0.0.0** and now getting a new error "**Connection Refused**"

```
status_channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:6667'))
```

The insecure gRPC connection should be established and data should be flown between client and server. Instead of getting a connectivity error.

Comment: Am curious if you've solved this. Having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround could be to run the docker container with **--net=host** locally.

`$ docker run -d --net=host <image_name>`

This is because localhost can resolve to IPv6 which docker port-forwarding is not friendly to. If failure to bind the IPv6 address will cause the IPv4 binding to fail as well.

Or you can also enable IPv6 for docker from the following: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/

Answer (score 0):

While trying to run the grpc server from docker, my grpc insecure channel contains the following:

```
server.add_insecure_port(f'{os.environ.get("HOST")}:{os.environ.get("PORT")}')
```

Then I override this variable from the .env for python where:

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=50001
```

This worked like a charm. The connection was established and data was flown.